# Angular material: How to avoid focus on elements in background of backdrop?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, focus, angular-material

[Demo for Backdrop Focus issue](https://codepen.io/ajsun/pen/wXZaLj)

When I open the side navigation on **OPEN SIDE NAV** button click, **backdrop** comes in picture. But I'm able to focus the elements that are in background of backdrop pressing **TAB** or **SHIFT TAB**.

I don't want the focus to go to the background elements whenever **backdrop** is there?

Should I assign `tabindex=-1` for the background elements when there is a backdrop? Is there a better way?

**UPDATE:**

As seen from [this link for Angular material 6.3.2](https://material.angular.io/components/bottom-sheet/overview#accessibility), they provide **Focus trap** by default. But, I am using **Angular Material Design v1.1.1**. How can I achieve same functionality here?